# If microwave ovens and WiFi both operate on the same frequency

Tags: experimental-physics

Part of the electromagnetic spectrum in the microwave area is the light used to heat food in microwave ovens. The frequency of this light is very close to the frequencies used in Wifi networks (wireless internet). It would obviously be dangerous to live in a microwave oven. Why is not it dangerous to stay with all Wifi signals? It is the same frequency of light!

If microwave ovens and WiFi both operate on the same frequency, why is it not dangerous to cook food in it ??

// sorry for bad english

Comment: Because the microwave uses a much higher intensity than wifi.

Answer (score 4):

Microwave ovens and WiFi's both operate at approximately 2.4 GHz. This frequency is non-ionising, meaning that it is not energetic enough to break electrons away from atoms (which would be dangerous).

Rather, this radiation can only damage something by heating it up *thermally*. And WiFi is produced at too low a power to heat anything by any significant amount (you may have noticed that your blood doesn't boil if you stand near a router).